# Excel sum the lowest in column and get the header of lowest in row

Tags: excel

Please refer to the following example.

[image]

I would like to automate on how to get the column F and G which is the lowest and name respectively. And also at the bottom get the sum of the amount of the lowest values per bidder just like on the 59, 34, 0 and 55.

Comment: `MIN($B2:$E2)` should do for column F... For the column G see function `LOOKUP()`...

Comment: How about the sum of the Lowest for column sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In column F just do this and drag it down to all rows:

```
=MIN(B2:E2)
```

In column E do this:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MATCH(F2,B2:E2,0))
```

For the sum of the amount of the lowest values, just write this formula in F6:

```
=SUM(F2:F5)
```

In cell B6 use the following:

```
=SUMIFS($F$2:$F$5,$G$2:$G$5,B$1)
```

Comment: I want to automate on getting the 59 on `B6` it is 59 because bidder 1 won 29 and 30 from items 1 and 2.

Comment: Edited my answer above

Comment: If you think this is the correct solution, please click on the 'tick' mark.